# drawpoint and float issue

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'd like to increment point by point in the function y = x^2 with playing on a scale.
so I start by drawing point 2.00-4.00 then 2.01-4.0401, etc...
I get crazy as x stays at 2.0 in the loop and getting the value in debug it is always 2.0.

```
        int x = 2;
        int y = 4;
        int scale = 100;
        float xx = (float) x;
        float yy = (float) y;
        for(int k=0;k<scale;k++) {
            canvas.drawPoint((float) (xx*scale) , (float) (yy*scale), paint);
            xx = xx + (1/scale);
            yy = xx * xx;
        }
```

what am I doing stupid?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `scale` is an integer and 1/scale is zero. Try replacing it with `1/(float)scale`

Comment: just seeing your comment. I did accept it as an answer. did you get the credit for it?

Comment: I think you voted it up(thanks for that) but you did not accept it as the answer